# If or Where Clauses in xQuery

Tags: xml, xquery

I'm very new to xQuery and I've to write the query to do the following;

> Find all authors who have authored at least a book and an article in the same year

I wrote the following using `IF-Then-Else` clause;

```
for $a in doc("myDB.xml")/myDB
return if ($a/book//last_name/text() = $a/article//last_name/text() 
and $a/book/year = $a/article/year)
then $a//author
else()
```

and with `Where` Clause.

```
for $a in doc("myDB.xml")/myDB
where $a/book//last_name/text() = $a/article//last_name/text() 
and $a/book/year = $a/article/year
return $a//author
```

Both approaches are returning all authors.

XML is;

```
<myDB>
    <book>
        <title>ebXML : Concepts and Application</title>
        <author>
            <last_name>Gibb</last_name>
            <first_name>Brian</first_name>
        </author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <publisher>Wiley</publisher>
    </book>

    <article>
        <title>test title</title>
        <author>
            <last_name>Gibb</last_name>
            <first_name>Brian</first_name>
        </author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <publisher>test Wiley</publisher>
    </article>

    <book>
        <title>XML: Visual QuickStart Guide</title>
        <author>
            <last_name>Goldberg</last_name>
            <first_name>Kevin</first_name>
        </author>
        <author>
            <last_name>Doe</last_name>
            <first_name>John</first_name>
        </author>

        <year>2008</year>
        <publisher>Peachpit Press</publisher>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Beginning XML</title>
        <author>
            <last_name>Hunter</last_name>
            <first_name>David</first_name>
        </author>
        <year>2007</year>
        <publisher>Wrox</publisher>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Learning XML </title>
        <author>
            <last_name>Ray</last_name>
            <first_name>Erik</first_name>
        </author>
        <author>
            <last_name>Smith</last_name>
            <first_name>David</first_name>
        </author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <publisher>O'Reilly</publisher>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Professional XML</title>
        <author>
            <last_name>Evjen</last_name>
            <first_name>Bill</first_name>
        </author>
        <year>2007</year>
        <publisher>Wrox</publisher>
    </book>
    <article>
        <title>FileNet Integrates a New XML Editor for Non-Techies</title>
        <author>
            <last_name>Roe</last_name>
            <first_name>David</first_name>
        </author>
        <journal>CMS Wire</journal>
        <year>2009</year>
    </article>
    <article>
        <title>The Groundbreaking Potential of Codeless Ajax</title>
        <author>
            <last_name>Dusoe</last_name>
            <first_name>Jim</first_name>
        </author>
        <journal>Tech News World</journal>
        <year>2009</year>
        <pages>4</pages>
    </article>
    <article>
        <title>Windows and .NET Watch: Recognizing DSL opportunities</title>
        <author>
            <last_name>O'Brien</last_name>
            <first_name>Larry</first_name>
        </author>
        <journal>Software Development Times</journal>
        <year>2009</year>
    </article>
    <article>
        <title>An embedded XML Database: Oracle Berkeley DB XML</title>
        <author>
            <last_name>Gibb</last_name>
            <first_name>Brian</first_name>
        </author>
        <journal>The Register</journal>
        <year>2003</year>
        <pages>8</pages>
    </article>
    <article>
        <title>Open Source PostgreSQL 8.3 Better Suited For Web Applications </title>
        <author>
            <last_name>Babcock</last_name>
            <first_name>Charles</first_name>
        </author>
        <journal>Information Week</journal>
        <year>2008</year>
        <pages>1</pages>
    </article>
</myDB>
```

I'm not getting the authors who wrote at least one book and one article in the same year rather I'm getting the list of all authors. I know that there is something logically wrong in the queries because I am not an expert of xQuery. Can somebody help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that XPath statements don't behave the way you expect them to in your query. They are simply selecting sequences of XML - so when you compare them, it will return true if any value on the left matches any value on the right. Because each comparison returns true, it always returns `$a//author`, every `author` in the document.

I think you want:

```
for $b in doc("myDB.xml")/myDB/book
let $articles:= doc("myDB.xml")/myDB/article[year=$b/year]
where ($b/author = $articles/author)
return $b/author
```

Comment: I don't think this will yield the correct result. Suppose there is a book which was authored by A and B and an article authored only by A in the same year. Your query will output both A and B, which is not correct.

Comment: @dirkk That's correct that this will not return distinct XML. It could be made to work by using a key, but I didn't think it was elemental to OP's question and would complicate the query. Also note that your example returns a string, not XML.

Answer (score 0):

`for` has to be used on an iterating item, but myDB appears just one time.

What the following query does is to get all authors ones and the check if they have an article which has the same year as a book they authored.

```
let $doc := doc("myDB.xml")/myDB
for $author in distinct-values($doc/*/author)
where $doc/article[author = $author][year = $doc/book[author = $author]/year]
return $author
```

Comment: It's working but I had to accept one answer so I accepted the one who posted first. +1 for your answer too. thanks